# Kivy Image Collision

Tags: python, image, kivy, collision

Is it possible to check if two images are overlapping or colliding in kivy?

I am using ScreenManager, and have a moving image that I am controlling. I want to check if it collides, and when that happens I want its pos to change (-)negatively.

I don't know what code to include. But here is some that is somewhat relevent.

Py Code:

```
xnum = 0.53
ynum = 0.412
xmovement = 0.0889
ymovement = 0.05
movementt = 0.1

class L1(Screen):
    screensize()
def animate_down_button(self, widget, *args):
    global ynum
    global ymovement
    global movementt
    ynum -= ymovement
    anim = Animation(y_hint=ynum, duration=movementt)
    anim.start(widget)
    pass

def animate_up_button(self, widget, *args):
    global ynum
    global ymovement
    ynum += ymovement
    anim = Animation(y_hint=ynum, duration=movementt)
    anim.start(widget)
    pass

def animate_right_button(self, widget, *args):
    global xnum
    global xmovement
    xnum += xmovement
    anim = Animation(x_hint=xnum, duration=movementt)
    anim.start(widget)
    pass

def animate_left_button(self, widget, *args):
    global xnum
    global xmovement
    xnum -= xmovement
    anim = Animation(x_hint=xnum, duration=movementt)
    anim.start(widget)
    pass

def play_nav(self):
    if nav:
        nav.play()
```

Kv Code:

```
<L1>:
    name: "L1"
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            source: 'background.jpg'
            size: root.width, root.height
        Rectangle:
            source: 'Mazebg.png'
            size: root.width*0.7, root.height*0.6
            pos: root.width*0.5 - root.width*0.35, root.height*0.32
        Rectangle:
            source: 'Maze1.png'
            size: root.width*0.7, root.height*0.6
            pos: root.width*0.5 - root.width*0.35, root.height*0.32
        Rectangle:
            source: 'Star.png'
            size: root.width*1.5, root.height*0.25
            pos: (root.width*-0.125), root.height*0.92

    Button:
        pos_hint: {"x":0.01, "top":0.995}
        size_hint: 0.15, 0.075
        background_normal: 'BackArrow.png'
        background_down: 'BackArrowPressed.png'
        on_release: root.play_nav()
        on_release: app.root.current = "GameMenu"
    Image:
        id: mazeball
        source: 'ball.png'
        size_hint: 0.07, 0.07
        x_hint: 0.53
        y_hint: 0.412
        pos_hint: {"x": self.x_hint, "top": self.y_hint}
    Button:
        pos_hint: {"x":0.4, "top":0.17}
        size_hint: 0.2, 0.1
        background_normal: 'PadDown.png'
        background_down: 'PadDownPressed.png'
        on_release: root.play_nav()
        on_press: root.animate_down_button(mazeball)

    Button:
        pos_hint: {"x":0.4, "top":0.31}
        size_hint: 0.2, 0.1
        background_normal: 'PadUp.png'
        background_down: 'PadUpPressed.png'
        on_release: root.play_nav()
        on_press: root.animate_up_button(mazeball)
    Button:
        pos_hint: {"x":0.525, "top": 0.235}
        size_hint: 0.2, 0.1
        background_normal: 'PadRight.png'
        background_down: 'PadRightPressed.png'
        on_release: root.play_nav()
        on_press: root.animate_right_button(mazeball)
    Button:
        pos_hint: {"x":0.275, "top": 0.235}
        size_hint: 0.2, 0.1
        background_normal: 'PadLeft.png'
        background_down: 'PadLeftPressed.png'
        on_release: root.play_nav()
        on_press: root.animate_left_button(mazeball)
```

Comment: Consider using [collide_widget()](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.collide_widget) to determine if the `Images` collide.

Comment: @JohnAnderson does an image count as a widget, 
and how would I use that method?

Comment: An `Image` is a `Widget`. The link I provided gives an example of how to use it.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I don't think this works if I am using screenmanager, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I would suggest trying it before you decide that it won't work.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I am trying